# Parsing a URL (as a string) and splicing each sub-page into an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, url

Given the url (string) `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, how could I split it up into an array that contains data like the following: `questions`,`ask`. How would I make this work for an infinite amount of slashes?

The way I am thinking of doing it would be to use `URL.parse` in Node.JS and then use `STRING.split('/')` to separate the string into an array.

Would this be the correct way to do it? Is there a quicker way?

Comment: `URL.parse` does the dirty work for you (getting the `path`), leaving you the easy part. I'd say splitting by `/` is definitely a fine way to go to get each "sub-page into an array". You could of course use a regular expression, but I feel like it's more straightforward/readable with the `split`

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, that is the best way to do it.  Alternatively you could just ignore the first parts of the split:

```
URL_STRING.split('/').slice(3)
```